# How can I create facet panels from separate dataframes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 6 dataframes like the one below, only differing in "count" values. The dataframes are named a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6. a1 is given below.

```
year count
1981 2
1982 8
1983 5
1984 6
1985 6
1986 4
1987 2
1988 2
1989 6
1990 5
```

I want to make a 6 panel figure like the one below where I have

```
1. Panel names as a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6.
2. x-axis is year for each dataframe
3. y-axis is count for each dataframe
```

I know how to do this if I had a single dataframe (Melt+Faced_Grid). But how can I do the same in ggplott2 when the data is in 6 different dataframes.

[image]

Comment: `dplyr::bind_rows(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, id = panel)` then plot with facets.

Comment: Next time, put your data frames [in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17499013/903061).

Comment: @Axeman I am getting this error: object 'panel' not found

Comment: Sorry, it should be `'panel'` instead. Ben's solution is equivalent.

Comment: I tried that actually. I am getting this: Error: cannot convert object to a data frame

Comment: it should be `.id`, not `id`.

Comment: Works now..............

Comment: The panel names are 1,2,3 etc. It would be nice to rename them to a1,a2 on the fly....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set.seed(1001)
a1 <- data.frame(year=2000:2009,count=sample(1:20,size=10,replace=TRUE))
a2 <- data.frame(year=2000:2009,count=sample(1:20,size=10,replace=TRUE))
dList <- setNames(list(a1,a2),paste0("a",1:2))
```

You can use `lapply()` to add a `frame` column to each data set, but `plyr::ldply` offers a shortcut:

```
library("plyr")
dAll <- ldply(dList,identity,.id="frame")
```

Alternatively you can use `dplyr::bind_rows`, as @Axeman points out in comments above:

```
library("dplyr")
dAll <- bind_rows(a1,a2,.id="frame")
```

Now it's easy with `facet_wrap()`:

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(dAll,aes(year,count))+geom_point()+facet_wrap(~frame)
```

Comment: Thank you. I wish I knew R this well.. Can you please tell me what this is doing: "paste0("a",1:2)"? Specially the a?

Comment: @maximusdooku If you run that line of code, `paste0("a", 1:2)`, I bet you can figure out what it's doing. If you're stuck, look at the help `?paste0`.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you.

Comment: Quick question: If I don't want to use serials like a1, a2 etc., and instead want to use some other random names (say, cow,bull,hen,sky,water,space), how would I need to modify this part: paste0("a",1:2)?

Comment: `dNames <- c("cow","bull","hen","water","space"); setNames(list(...),dNames)` (or `dList <- list(...); names(dList) <- dNames`)